# What's the meaning of F(string) in C++?

Tags: c++, arduino

Currently I'm writing C++ code on Arduino. In an example, I find a expression

```
Serial.print(F("Disconnected from central:"));
```

It's obvious that this statement is used to send string to the serial, but why it uses F(string) instead of using string directly?

I try to google it but with no results. If someone know it, I would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is either a function called `F` or a macro `F` with a single parameter.

Comment: https://www.baldengineer.com/arduino-f-macro.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This macro is Arduino-specific, it's not "C++" as such.

It places the string in flash memory, to conserve RAM.

It means the string cannot be modified when the program runs.

One current definition is:

```
#define F(slit) (reinterpret_cast<const __FlashStringHelper *>(PSTR(slit)))
```

[See the source code for more](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/WString.h).

Comment: This is a bit off topic, but I can't help wondering why they didn't just put string literals in flash memory by default. Is there some advantage to putting them in RAM by default?

Comment: @IanAbbott I beleive [this page](https://www.iar.com/support/tech-notes/compiler/strings-with-iccavr-2.x/) has some discussion, it's problematic when you have pointers to strings on the AVR platform.

Comment: So I see! Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

`F()` is one of the most powerful functions, which was added with the `1.0` release of the `IDE`. I keep mixing the terms `macro` and `function`.  `F()` really isn’t a `function`, it is a `#define macro` which lives in `WString.h`

```
#define F(string_literal) (reinterpret_cast<const __FlashStringHelper *>(PSTR(string_literal)))
```

It is a macro, which use for storing `strings` in `flash memory` rather than `RAM`.